# Kotlin , code enters if statemant even when condition is false

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement

I'm really confused here ... looks like a really silly mistake but I don't know what's happening. Here's little snippet of my code :

```
if (tempDeltaDeviation > standardDeltaDeviation) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "handleMessage: plus $tempDeltaDeviation : $standardDeltaDeviation")
                        scaleUpAnimation(deltaAnimStep, "Delta", binding.deltaImg)
}
```

Really basic stuff, right ? Well checking the logs I can see :

```
handleMessage: plus 1.57756888292539E14 : 7.8364593205657E13
```

Dunno but last time I was checking 1 was much smaller than 7 so why app enters if statement ?

Comment: Is either variable local or instance variables, if the latter is it mutated and read from different threads?

Comment: tempDeltaDeviation is an instance variable  that is calculated every 60 sec

Comment: These values are scientific annotations, what are their type?

Comment: tempDeltaDeviation and standardDeltaDeviation  are Double type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1.57756888292539E14` is in fact larger than `7.8364593205657E13`.

These numbers are represented in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) which is used to work with very small or very large numbers. `1.57756888292539E14` means: `1.57756888292539 * 10^14`. By increasing the number after `E` by one we actually increase the resulting number 10 times. By increasing it by 6, we increase the resulting number million times (10^6 = 1000000).

Making things simple, your numbers are really:

- 157756888292539 (1.57756888292539 * 100000000000000)
- 78364593205657 (7.8364593205657 * 10000000000000)

As you can see, the first number is actually bigger.

Comment: LOL! I didnt notice E at the end! :D Thanks